# How to know when redux-saga saga has run to completion?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, next.js

I'm working with redux-saga inside a NextJS context, using next-redux-saga.  The documentation says

```
 /**
   * next-redux-saga depends on `runSagaTask` and `sagaTask` being attached to the store.
   *
   *   `runSagaTask` is used to rerun the rootSaga on the client when in sync mode (default)
   *   `sagaTask` is used to await the rootSaga task before sending results to the client
   *
   */

  store.runSagaTask = () => {
    store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  }
```

If my saga is fetching data thus:

```
function * loadDataSaga () {
  try {
    console.log('fetching data in saga')

    const res = yield fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    const data = yield res.json()
    yield put(loadDataSuccess(data))
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(failure(err))
  }
}
```

How does next-redux-saga know when the saga has run to completion, that is, as I assume, when the data is loaded?

Comment: there is a `done` promise field on the task (in redux-saga 1 it is `toPromise()` method)

Comment: @MartinKadlec -- Excellent -- and when we say 'task' we mean the entire generator, that is 'loadDataSaga', right?  (I'm new to sagas).  And if this saga is combined inside a root saga, would the same apply to the root saga, that there is a `done` field for that as well to indicate 'completion'?  What if a child saga of the root saga is in a permanent loop, that is, that pattern where the saga is in a `while` statement, listening for actions?  Would the root (and child) saga ever be `done`?

Comment: well, task is an object created by redux-saga library describing a running saga https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#task ... I think it will never be done if there is an never ending infinite loop inside it.

Comment: @MartinKadlec -- Has the `done` field been renamed to `toPromise`?  In the example code from NextJS it's `done` and next-redux-saga works fine, but in the code of the project I'm joining it seems to be `isPromise` and next-redux-saga is not waiting for the saga to complete before rendering the page.

Comment: Yes, it was changed in the v1 of redux-saga https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v1.0.0 .... it was released 5 days ago so it makes sense the boilerplate repos are not udpated yet

Comment: @MartinKadlec -- That's helpful to know.  I believe the problem I'm running into (in connecting Next.js and 'redux-saga', which is my current task) is that the NPM package 'next-redux-saga' is depending on the 'done' field to work properly.  I downloaded the package and tried simply changing the reference to 'done' to 'toPromise', but that didn't work.  Do you have any idea if a direct substitution like that would work?  Do I need to call 'toPromise', that is, substituting 'done' with 'toPromise()'?

Comment: @MartinKadlec -- The creator of the 'next-redux-saga' package says he has no time to fix it, so I'm keen to give it a try.  Do you perhaps know if there are any docs explaining the internal changes in 'redux-saga', so I can understand what 'toPromise' is doing?

Comment: the change was pretty simple really, they just replaced the `done` getter with `toPromise` method. You can see the commit here https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/1231/commits/f1c0845cdc53ec1bc021e41dccbe925f99279762 `src/internal/proc.js`